# How to store HashMap in Hibernate - MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, insert, hashmap

I saw couple of similar topics, but unfortunately none of them solved my problem.

I'm writing sale system. There're many of suppliers and buyers. Each supplier has different prices of different products, and same it's with buyers.

Firstly I've solved it like that (but I have no idea what to do next..):

```
public class Buyer {

    //key = type of product, value = price for that product
    private Map<ProductType, Double> productPrices;

public class Order {

    //key = type of product, value = quantity of products
    private Map<ProductType, Double> orderedProducts;
```

Here is my service to calculate order (it's not final version, I'll change returning type to some object instead of that "Frankenstein"..), so don't be scary.

```
// key = product type, value = ( quantity, price)
public Map<ProductType, Map<Double, Double>> calculateOrder(Order order, Buyer buyer) {

    AtomicReference<Double> totalSum = new AtomicReference<>((double) 0);
    Map<ProductType, Map<Double, Double>> resultOrder = new HashMap<>();

    order.getOrderedProducts().forEach((type, quantity) -> {
        double price = buyer.getProductPrices().get(type);
        double sum = quantity * price;

        resultOrder.put(type, new HashMap<>());
        resultOrder.get(type).put(quantity, sum);

        totalSum.updateAndGet(v1 -> v1 + sum);
    });

    return resultOrder;
}
```

What's more: prices of products will change really often for every buyer/supplier.

So the question is: how to put that Map(s) into database? Of course with keeping clean code without some "Frankensteins" and to have easy access to all data?

I'll be really greteful for any help!

PS. To simplify problem, I've deleted useless attributes of Entities to keep focus just on staff which is important for that problem.

PS2. Yes, I'll change double to BigDecimal, just now for easier calculating I'm using doubles.

Comment: [This article on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-persisting-maps) describes a way on how to store maps with Hibernate.